# If the bill threshold limit exceeds we need to stop the instance automatically. How?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How the ec2 instance automatically stop when the bill limit is reached.

I need if the bill threshold limit exceeds the instance want to stop automatically

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in/native way to do this. What you can do is set up a [billing alert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html), which would then trigger a Lambda function which can shut down or terminate your resources.